# Parse string as date contains words

Tags: ios7, nsdateformatter

I want to parse "DATE: 12-9-2014 TIME: 20-13-59" this string to NSDate. I have tried it parsing it using format

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"DATE: dd-MM-yyyy TIME: HH-mm-ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStamp];
NSLog(@"ASD: %@", date);
```

It returns null. What i am doing wrong, please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add quotes around the parts of the date string that are literal, and are not formatting characters:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"'DATE:' dd-MM-yyyy 'TIME:' HH-mm-ss"];
```